# Accessing lists through loops

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a program in which I have a store with items that have set prices. The user begins with $100 and and is prompted to enter the item number that will be purchased(shoes is "1", socks is "2", etc). The cost of the item of the item should be subtracted from the beginning total and user should be asked to buy another item. If cost exceeds the money left then it should print out a "not enough funds statement" and be asked to buy another item again. Entering "0" should cause the program to exit. The first loop of my code simply prints out the items available and the prices, but I am confused on how to set up the rest of my loops so it subtracts the right total each time and does not end up being an infinite loop.

Code so far:

```
def main():
    print("You have $100 in funds available")
    wallet = 100
    items = ["shoes", "socks", "hat", "belt", "blouse", "dress", "tie"]
    prices = [54.99, 7.11, 6.49, 22.58, 21.73, 38.99, 14.83]

    for i in range( len(items)):
        print(i+1, "-", items[i], "\t$",prices[i])

    #itemNum = input("Please choose an item # to purchase, or '0' to quit: ")
    itemNum = ""
    while itemNum != "0":
        itemNum = input("Please choose an item # to purchase, or '0' to quit: ")
        for x in items:
            if wallet > prices[x]:
                wallet = wallet - prices[x]
                print("You have $",wallet,"in funds left")


            else:
                print("Sorry but you are unable to afford that item")

main()
```

Comment: use a `dict` instead of two `lists` to store items as key and values as price

Comment: FYI... you are asking them to type in the item number of what they want to buy, but then you aren't using that information. Why loop through items when they have asked for a specific one?

Comment: `I am confused on how to set up my loops so it subtracts the right total each time and does not end up being an infinite loop`. I suppose the first important thing to do is to establish a breaking condition. Should the loop break when there are no more funds? Or when the funds remaining are insufficient to purchase anything else? Or how about when the user doesn't want anything else? Once you establish that, the `while` logic is straight forward and your forever condition is taken care of. Re: the two lists, I would use a dictionary for better access.

Comment: The loop should only break when the user enter a "0". Even if there are not sufficient funds, the user should still be asked what he/she still wants to buy, again.